# How to Run go program in CWP

Tags: apache, go, centos, devops, cwp

I have a CentOS vps with **CWP** installed. I want to run **Go language** program in one of my domains.
Please guide me.

Answer (score -1):

for this you should use some third party like NGINX.
Go to Web Server Settings > Select WebServers
by default it is jus apache, you should select NGINX and then run your go program on a specific port then try redirecting the port on your domain with NGINX.

for more information about CWP web server setting go to
https://clients.hostsailor.com/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase/286/How-to-change-your-Webserver-in-CWP.html

for more information about NGINX:
https://www.nginx.com/